# PCA algorithm on low coverage features

Tags: vector-spaces, machine-learning, clustering

Suppose I am using PCA on traditional user-item matrix (each user for each row, each feature for each column), and I want to use PCA to lower feature dimension and use compacted features for a two class classification problem.

Suppose some features has very low coverage (very few users has this feature, all others are None), but such features are has strong prediction power for classification (e.g. measured by mutual information). Wondering PCA algorithm will ignore such features since its coverage is very low? Thanks.

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 1):

PCA will still give strong weights to these features, so long as it is evident from your data that they have a strong effect.

To be more concrete, PCA is equivalent to the eigenvalue decomposition of the Covariance Matrix $C_{xx}$ = $\frac1{n-1}*X*X^T$.

If your data implies that the data is highly variant along certain dimensions, PCA will essentially amplify this difference, providing you with an optimal coordinate system to view your data which emphasizes which coordinates play a large role in the values of your data. Your eigenvector matrix will provide your new basis.

In MATLAB:

```
[V, D] = eig(cov(X))
```

should do the trick, where V will yield your new coordinates (Principal Components)

I'm sure Numpy or Scipy has some equivalent functionality that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thanks E. Nusinovich, my confusion is how PCA handles feature value `not exist` scenario. Supposing for the features, some of them have value `1`, some of them have value `0` (both case are small coverage, but it is very distinguishable if they valued `1` and valued `0` for the two class), but large numbers are feature value `not exist` cases (which I mean low coverage), wondering how PCA will treat users (row) with existing feature values, and users (row) with non-existing feature values?

Comment: BTW, another confusion is, I think PCA does not know how I use the compacted features -- whether I use them for classification, or regression, or something else, etc. How did PCA knows if the features are distinguishable or not for a two class classification problem? (I mean the user item matrix is feature matrix, classification label is not in the matrix, how did PCA knows and utilize it?) Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa Ultimately, PCA doesn't _know_ anything per se. I would suggest checking out http://www.lauradhamilton.com/introduction-to-principal-component-analysis-pca. I also don't understand what you mean by "not exist" cases -- ultimately you should have a data matrix where your rows are individual observations, and each column contains distinct information. Alternately, your columns could have observations and rows separate different fields, but then covariance is defined in the opposite way $X^T*X$. If you are attempting to classify data, PCA doesn't do this, only reducing data complexity.

Comment: Thanks E. Nusinovich, for not exist cast, I mean for example, we have a matrix recording if a user (row) purchased some item (column) from a web site or offline. Since we collect some data from some e-commerce web site, we know if a user purchased, or not purchased (suppose some items are exclusively sold on the web site), but we cannot collect all data (e.g. some offline purchase we cannot collect), there are not exist cell in the matrix (not exist means we do not know if the user purchased or not).

Comment: (cont'd) in such situation, how do you think PCA handles the missing values? thx.

Comment: PCA will not function, depending on the implementation, unless you have a complete matrix. I would set missing values to zero, and take into account that you have an incomplete look at what's going on because of limited resources. @LinMa

Comment: Thanks E. Nusinovich for the reply and vote up. Let us ignore the missing value part. If in the matrix it is just user and purchased item, then I use PCA to generate compact features, and how do I know if the compact features works well for a classification problem -- I have this confusion since when PCA is generating compacting features, it does not know how I utilize the features (e.g. for classification or not), so not confident compacted features works well for a classification problem? Thanks.